# C - code compatibility

Tags: c, compatibility, ansi-c

How to make sure, that my code is compatible with every gcc compiler set to the most strict level? Is there any tester tool or do I need to test it manually somehow? Thanks

Comment: There's no way to be completely sure (especially since there are cases of undefined behavior which are almost impossible to detect at compile time), but using `-ansi -pedantic -Wall -Wextra` could be a good start.

Comment: thanks. I tried just -Wall at first, there were few warnings that I fixed, but with -ansi, there are around 15 very weird errors/warnings. Couple of times it says that there is unused variable (which is used of course), some parse errors and some other warnings. Should I be worried? I don't see in my code any parse error, or unused variables, so I don't really understand why there are so many errors

Comment: `-ansi` means C89 (shudder), so for example you can't mix declarations and code, you can't use `//` comments, you have "implicit int" and implicit function declarations. `-std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors` is a good combination, IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every gcc compiler is easy, just use an old one and it will compile for sure with the newer ones.

If you want it to compile with any compiler it's a bit more hard. As suggested you might use the -ansi switch to disable gcc extensions.

Comment: Or `-std=c99` to use the newer ISO/ANSI standard (`-ansi` is equivalent to `-std=c89`)